# Procedimiento almacenado con varios valores en una misma columna con 'Where in'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy trabajando con sql management 2018 y realice la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from Matriculas
where estudientes in (10002,10004,10005)
```

Y me gustaria generar un procedimiento almacenado el cual pueda recibir todos esos valores pero el que hice al ejecutarlo me marca error al convertir varchar a float, este es mi sp

```
create procedure sp_consolidado
@parametros float
as
    select * from Matriculas
    where estudiantes in (@parametros)
go
```

alguien me podria ayudar, aun no comprendo mucho de sql pero intento mejorar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso recomiendo definir la variable de entrada como **VARCHAR**, esto permitirá mandar los "**N**" valores separados por coma, y posteriormente recuperarlos en la consulta con la función **STRING_SPLIT**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [NombreEsquema].[NombreProcedimiento]
  @vParametros varchar(900) = '0'    --EJ: 'Valor1,Valor2,Valor3'
AS
  SELECT * FROM Matriculas
  ...
  ...
  WHERE estudiantes IN ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@vParametros, ',');
GO
```

Cabe mencionar que se debe mandar el parametro con el tipo correspondiente, en este caso "**String**".

Comment: Te agradezco tu ayuda, esto es lo que estaba buscando :)